# Undefined but existing

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

Here's my code:

js

```
var priorities = {
  banner: '300',
  avatar: '301'
};
var editableDiv = $('*[data-edit]');

editableDiv.append('<div class="overlay-edit"></div>');
editableDiv.each(function(index, value) {
  var actualPriorities = value.getAttribute("data-edit");

  console.log(actualPriorities);
  console.log(priorities[actualPriorities]);
});
```

html/php

```
<div class="hexagon-wrap" style="height:<?php echo $this->outterHeight;?>px; width:<?php echo $this->outterWidth;?>px"
<?php
if($this->htmlOptions) {
    foreach ($this->htmlOptions as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . "=" . $value . "&nbsp";
    }
}
?>
>
```

$this->htmlOptions contains

```
array('data-edit' => 'avatar')
```

The output :

```
banner
300
avatar 
undefined
```

I do not understand why my last result is undefined. When I'm trying

```
priorities['avatar']; // ouput is 301
```

The output is good.

Comment: Share the HTML where `data-edit` attribute is defined. Otherwise we can't help you since we don't have a crystal ball

Comment: PS: Don't declare the priorities `Object` inside the `each` loop.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, done !

Comment: @Cristy, I will change it !

Comment: Look at the generated HTML. It's making something like `<div class="hexagon-wrap" style="height:100px; width:100px" data-edit=avatar&nbsp>` which is obviously broken.

Comment: @Juhana, oh yes ! I have the &nbsp written in raw in the HTML !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the no breaking space character, and you can improve the code wrapping in quotes:

```
<div class="hexagon-wrap" style="height:<?php echo $this->outterHeight;?>px; width:<?php echo $this->outterWidth;?>px"
<?php
if($this->htmlOptions) {
    foreach ($this->htmlOptions as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . "='" . $value . "' ";
    }
}
?>
```

Note that I change the `&nbsp;` with the `'` (with a real space to separate the attributes)

Comment: Thank you ! It was the problem !

Comment: You are welcome, since you share the whole code we are able to help you. Remember it next time ;) See you soon!

Comment: Note that this will work reliably only if `$value` never contains quotes.

Comment: I think he can also write the `echo` statement as `echo "{$key}='{$value}' "` for better readability.